# Overlapping execution but only execute expensive task inside once

Tags: c#, async-await

I have an async method, which sometimes is called faster than its execution time, leading to overlap and executing an expensive task more often than necessary.
My goal is to have the expensive task executed only once for all calls overlapping the first call in the overlap.

```
public static void MethodA() { Console.Write("A"); }
public static Task MethodB() { Console.Write("B"); return Task.Delay(500); }
public static void MethodC() { Console.Write("C"); }
public static async Task MethodAsync() {
    //TODO: Block any additional calls until first call has finished.
    //      Additional calls then exit immediately afterwards.
    Console.Write("<");
    MethodA();
    await MethodB();
    MethodC();
    Console.Write(">");
}
public static void Main() {
    MethodAsync();
    MethodAsync();
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Given the above example MethodAsync is called twice with no delay which leads to MethodB executing twice.
I'd like to have the first call execute normally and the second call wait (asynchronously) until the first call has finished and then exit without executing anything afterwards.

The best I've come up with uses a SemaphoreSlim and an integer variable: https://dotnetfiddle.net/7H8SZx

I'm wondering if there is a different/nicer way to do it.

Edit:
Given the example above (not the link) the output would be something like `<AB<ABC>C>`.
The aim is to have something like `<AB<C>>` or if I make 10 calls without delay (which practically never happens) `<AB<<<<<<<<<C>>>>>>>>>>`

Another example:
The MethodAsync Method is awaited 2 times without delay, then after 2s it is awaited another three times without delay.
The aim is to have `<AB<C>><AB<<C>>>`

Comment: Why aren't you awaiting `MethodAsync()`?

Comment: I've only include the Main method to make a working example. The actual Project has the calls in different places.

Comment: You aren't doing it correctly though and the issue is not awaiting the async call. Because you aren't using `await`, the next method starts to execute while the first one is still going. Using `await` would solve that problem.

Comment: Is MethodAsync() being called by separate threads?  Otherwise an Await solves the problem.

Comment: Maybe you want to tell us the *real* problem you want to solve. It may be solved differently and more easily...

Comment: No only the UI Thread calls the function.

Comment: The code in your question will output "<AB<ABC>C>".  What is the desired output?

Comment: The desired output is for example <AB<C>> (See https://dotnetfiddle.net/7H8SZx In that example the two overlapping calls only execute the A/B/C Methods once and then again after the overlap has passed)

Comment: And the desired output from say 4 `MethodAsync()` calls instead of 2 (currently "<AB<AB<AB<ABC>C>C>C>")?  If all you're trying to achieve is "ABC ABC ABC ABC" there are much easier ways to do this...

Comment: No, I want to avoid calling the A/B/C Methods if there is still a call of MethodAsync executing. Please see the example link given in the question. It does exactly what I want, but I'm hoping for a less convoluted way to do it.

Comment: So this is a multi-threading problem not a async/await problem.  It doesn't seem you should be using await/async at all.  If you're trying to execute a method on another thread to keep your UI Thread active.  If this is the case, you need to update your question.

Comment: How can 10 calls produce `<AB<<<<<<<<<C>>>>>>>>>>`.  There should be 10 A's, B's and C's.

Comment: As I've stated I want to purposely skip them if there is already another call underway.

Comment: An alternative, though I wouldn't say it's nicer: https://dotnetfiddle.net/YzS2De

Comment: I'd want to avoid the additional object creation for every call, but the use of Interlocked.CompareExchange is a nice idea. It ensures that once the call which does the actual work finishes, the next call will start again doing the heavy lifting even there are still awaiting calls left. I incorporated it in a class: https://gist.github.com/DvdKhl/22beb783902fa7e676ba87b2dc50cb51

Answer (score 0):

A semaphore is the way to go, but you can make it a little simpler than your fiddle example; something like this:

```
static SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);

public static async Task MethodAsync()
{
    Console.Write("<");

    if (await semaphore.WaitAsync(TimeSpan.Zero))
    {
         MethodA();
         await MethodB();
         MethodC();
         semaphore.Release();
    }

    Console.Write(">");
}
```

Comment: `I'd like to have [...] the second call wait (asynchronously) until the first call has finished` Unless I'm mistaken, your answer does not cover this requirement, the second call will exit immediately

Comment: What he'd *like to have* is actually incorrectly described.  What this should say is I want a Queue of functionality for a single method so that it is only called once.

Comment: @KevinGosse - as I understand it, he effectively wants an entire `MethodAsync()` to be skipped if an event fires and the previous event is still being handled.  @OP - please clarify further if not the case.

Comment: I wouldn't say skipped, it sounds like he wants it Queue'd.  Which then begs the question, how many can be queued?

Comment: If queued, he can just remove the `TimeSpan.Zero` and the `if` :)  The counter code in the fiddle made me think he wants it skipped, though...

Comment: @KevinGosse Yes I want to skip it (no Queue) but have the it wait until the method call which does the actual work has finished, otherwise the overlapping calls would exit too soon.

Comment: @Arokh why would a call to a method that does nothing exit too soon?

Comment: Because the first call hasn't finished yet, but is required for all further calls.

Comment: @Arokh do you understand that calling Await does not create a new thread?  Thus calls to `MethodAsync` need to be done by a new thread.  If it's done by a new thread then any additional calls are using a thread to do nothing while waiting for the last `MethodAsync()` call to end.  Thats an insane waste of resources.

Comment: As far as I can see the example ( https://dotnetfiddle.net/7H8SZx ) does not fire additional threads (Tested with 100 calls with no delay) neither is there any spike in memory or cpu usage.
And an overlap occurs not that often and when it does there are three overlapping calls at most.